# summarise a statistical value based on date duration in R

Tags: r, date, statistics, rstudio

I have a small issue about the question above. To be specific, I have two date variables in R with starting and end date say: one case starts in 2000-1-1 ends in 2000-4-1.

I also have a variable that records one medical result within these dates, say in 2000-1-1 the result is 20; and in 2000-2-1/2000-3-1/2000-4-1 the results are 30,30,and 50.

I want to calculate the mean of these variable based on each duration of dates, in our cases the mean will be 32.5 (130/4).

How can I achieve it in R studio? Thanks in advance.

Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the aggregate function to calculate the sums of your values for each quarter.

**EDITED** Looks like you're not using quarters of the year as your time interval, but trimesters? so jan-apr is a category, may-aug is another, and sep-dec is the last??

If that is the case you can't use lubridate::quarter() so you will need to write your own vectorized function that deals with this trimester and assigns each a number. This can easily be done by:

```
trimester <- function(date){
    if(lubridate::month(date) >= 1 & lubridate::month(date) <= 4) return(1)
    if(lubridate::month(date) >= 5 & lubridate::month(date) <= 8) return(2)
    if(lubridate::month(date) >= 9 & lubridate::month(date) <= 12) return(3)}
```

`VectorizedTrimester <- Vectorize(trimester)`

Then your actual aggregation can be achieved by:

`aggregate(formula = OrderValue ~ VectorizedTrimester(OrderDate), FUN = mean)`

That is the best I can give you with what you provided, consider using variable names and actual code in your question next time for a better answer.